# Trouble computing cost in logistic regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am taking the course from Andrew Ng on Machine Learning on Coursera.  In this assginment, I am working to calculate the cost function using logistic regression in MatLab, but am receiving "Error using sfminbx (line 27)
Objective function is undefined at initial point. fminunc cannot continue.".

I should add that the cost J within the costFunction function below is NaN because the log(sigmoid(X * theta)) is a -Inf vector.  I'm sure this is related to the exception.  Can you please help?

My cost function looks like the following:

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

  m = length(y); % number of training examples
  J = 0;
  grad = zeros(size(theta));

  h = sigmoid(theta * X);
  J    = - (1 / m) * ((log(h)' * y) + (log(1 - h)' * (1 - y)));
  grad = (1 / m) * X' * (h - y);

end
```

My code that calls this function looks like the following:

```
data = load('ex2data1.txt');
X = data(:, [1, 2]); y = data(:, 3);

[m, n] = size(X);

% Add intercept term to x and X_test
X = [ones(m, 1) X];

% Initialize fitting parameters
initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);

% Compute and display initial cost and gradient
[cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y);

fprintf('Cost at initial theta (zeros): %f\n', cost);
fprintf('Expected cost (approx): 0.693\n');
fprintf('Gradient at initial theta (zeros): \n');
fprintf(' %f \n', grad);
fprintf('Expected gradients (approx):\n -0.1000\n -12.0092\n -11.2628\n');

% Compute and display cost and gradient with non-zero theta
test_theta = [-24; 0.2; 0.2];
[cost, grad] = costFunction(test_theta, X, y);

fprintf('\nCost at test theta: %f\n', cost);
fprintf('Expected cost (approx): 0.218\n');
fprintf('Gradient at test theta: \n');
fprintf(' %f \n', grad);
fprintf('Expected gradients (approx):\n 0.043\n 2.566\n 2.647\n');
fprintf('\nProgram paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;


%% ============= Part 3: Optimizing using fminunc  =============
%  In this exercise, you will use a built-in function (fminunc) to find the
%  optimal parameters theta.

%  Set options for fminunc
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400, 'Algorithm', 'trust-
region');

%  Run fminunc to obtain the optimal theta
%  This function will return theta and the cost 

[theta, cost] = ...
    fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);

end
```

The dataset looks like the following:

34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
45.08327747668339,56.3163717815305,0
61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
75.02474556738889,46.55401354116538,1
76.09878670226257,87.42056971926803,1
84.43281996120035,43.53339331072109,1
95.86155507093572,38.22527805795094,0
75.01365838958247,30.60326323428011,0
82.30705337399482,76.48196330235604,1
69.36458875970939,97.71869196188608,1
39.53833914367223,76.03681085115882,0
53.9710521485623,89.20735013750205,1
69.07014406283025,52.74046973016765,1
67.94685547711617,46.67857410673128,0
70.66150955499435,92.92713789364831,1
76.97878372747498,47.57596364975532,1
67.37202754570876,42.83843832029179,0
89.67677575072079,65.79936592745237,1
50.534788289883,48.85581152764205,0
34.21206097786789,44.20952859866288,0
77.9240914545704,68.9723599933059,1
62.27101367004632,69.95445795447587,1
80.1901807509566,44.82162893218353,1
93.114388797442,38.80067033713209,0
61.83020602312595,50.25610789244621,0
38.78580379679423,64.99568095539578,0
61.379289447425,72.80788731317097,1
85.40451939411645,57.05198397627122,1
52.10797973193984,63.12762376881715,0
52.04540476831827,69.43286012045222,1
40.23689373545111,71.16774802184875,0
54.63510555424817,52.21388588061123,0
33.91550010906887,98.86943574220611,0
64.17698887494485,80.90806058670817,1
74.78925295941542,41.57341522824434,0
34.1836400264419,75.2377203360134,0
83.90239366249155,56.30804621605327,1
51.54772026906181,46.85629026349976,0
94.44336776917852,65.56892160559052,1
82.36875375713919,40.61825515970618,0
51.04775177128865,45.82270145776001,0
62.22267576120188,52.06099194836679,0
77.19303492601364,70.45820000180959,1
97.77159928000232,86.7278223300282,1
62.07306379667647,96.76882412413983,1
91.56497449807442,88.69629254546599,1
79.94481794066932,74.16311935043758,1
99.2725269292572,60.99903099844988,1
90.54671411399852,43.39060180650027,1
34.52451385320009,60.39634245837173,0
50.2864961189907,49.80453881323059,0
49.58667721632031,59.80895099453265,0
97.64563396007767,68.86157272420604,1
32.57720016809309,95.59854761387875,0
74.24869136721598,69.82457122657193,1
71.79646205863379,78.45356224515052,1
75.3956114656803,85.75993667331619,1
35.28611281526193,47.02051394723416,0
56.25381749711624,39.26147251058019,0
30.05882244669796,49.59297386723685,0
44.66826172480893,66.45008614558913,0
66.56089447242954,41.09209807936973,0
40.45755098375164,97.53518548909936,1
49.07256321908844,51.88321182073966,0
80.27957401466998,92.11606081344084,1
66.74671856944039,60.99139402740988,1
32.72283304060323,43.30717306430063,0
64.0393204150601,78.03168802018232,1
72.34649422579923,96.22759296761404,1
60.45788573918959,73.09499809758037,1
58.84095621726802,75.85844831279042,1
99.82785779692128,72.36925193383885,1
47.26426910848174,88.47586499559782,1
50.45815980285988,75.80985952982456,1
60.45555629271532,42.50840943572217,0
82.22666157785568,42.71987853716458,0
88.9138964166533,69.80378889835472,1
94.83450672430196,45.69430680250754,1
67.31925746917527,66.58935317747915,1
57.23870631569862,59.51428198012956,1
80.36675600171273,90.96014789746954,1
68.46852178591112,85.59430710452014,1
42.0754545384731,78.84478600148043,0
75.47770200533905,90.42453899753964,1
78.63542434898018,96.64742716885644,1
52.34800398794107,60.76950525602592,0
94.09433112516793,77.15910509073893,1
90.44855097096364,87.50879176484702,1
55.48216114069585,35.57070347228866,0
74.49269241843041,84.84513684930135,1
89.84580670720979,45.35828361091658,1
83.48916274498238,48.38028579728175,1
42.2617008099817,87.10385094025457,1
99.31500880510394,68.77540947206617,1
55.34001756003703,64.9319380069486,1
74.77589300092767,89.52981289513276,1

Comment: could you post the code for sigmoid function

Comment: I didn't write this code as this is a function within MatLab.  The documentation is below.   "sigmoid Compute sigmoid function
    g = sigmoid(z) computes the sigmoid of z."  My understanding is this should be 1/1+e^-(theta' * X)

Comment: I think there should be a file called sigmoid.m in the directory and you need to write the code for sigmoid activation. At least that's how it was when I did the course.

Comment: That fixed in Sarthak.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that you should have written `h = sigmoid(X * theta)` instead of `h = sigmoid(theta * X)`. I am getting the same answer from your code after changing this as I was getting from my code for the same assignment.

Comment: Are you receiving the correct (expected) cost and gradient values?  Also, are you receiving NaN for your cost values?

Comment: I am also doing the same course, so I just modified my code with yours, made the change that I have mentioned and it worked. I did not change anything else. Maybe you made some other change somewhere else?

Comment: I haven't made any other changes.  The code is still what I posted above. 
 Hmm, what version of MatLab are you running?  I wonder if that is somehow related.

Comment: So i am running 2016a. I also see one other difference from my code which I hadn't noticed before. This line `options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400, 'Algorithm', 'trust-region');` does not have the Algorithm setting in my code. If i add the algorithm option, that is giving another error. I can't replicate your error though.

Comment: I am running 2017a.  I did try multiple options for the line above and was receiving errors throughout.  Likely because the cost value is NaN, but don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Maybe just try with this: `options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);`. Also, I am pretty sure that the cost value should not be NaN.

Comment: I looked at the values for log(h), they never go to -Inf in the Example data set that is used. I have the same dataset as you.